# Play framework Scala actions

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

As someone new to Scala, can someone explain [the code here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActions)?

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

So I get that you're creating a new value called echo, from an Action trait (similar to a Java interface from what I can gather). `request` is some sort of argument, though I've never seen this syntax before -- what do the brackets and arrow `=>` signify?

I see that I create a `Result` object signifying a 200 response, and presumably returning that. But what sort of function am I returning from? A constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the new value echo is getting its value from the result of calling the function `Action.apply`, where `Action` is an object (scala singleton, sort of related to statics in Java).

The Action.apply function apparently takes, as its argument, a function and by convention would return a value of the type of the Action trait.

```
{ request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

Is a function from some type (the argument is labelled `request`) to some type (the return of the call to `Ok`).

Assuming you are coming from a Java background, the Java 8 lambdas use a very similar syntax.

Comment: Action seems to be a trait (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala)? So when you write `Action [some func]` you are actually calling `Action.apply` on that function?

Comment: In the file you linked there is `object Action extends ActionBuilder[Request]` and `trait ActionBuilder[+R[_]]` has an `apply` method which takes a `BodyParser` which extends `Function1`. In Scala it is convention to have a "companion object" for traits and classes which holds the sorts of things that would go into a class's static members/methods in java. in this case a factory method. In scala, if you call an object like "foo(stuff)" that's just syntactic sugar for "foo.apply(stuff)"

Answer (score 1):

An Action is a function that takes a request and yields a result (response). Within the expression `{}` you have a function literal (anonymous function) `request => Ok()`. Thus, `request` will be available within the body after the `=>`.

Since this is Scala, the last bit of the expression evaluated will be the result; that is, what's inside `Ok()` will be evaluated and then you the result will be generated.